# Getting Timestamp from PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get the timestamp in php. Using following code

```
$date = new DateTime();
        echo $date->getTimestamp();
```

error comes `getTimestamp() is undefined` however according to this

> http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

I need the format like 123456789

Comment: `(PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)` is probably the reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the `PHP 5 >= 5.3.0` on the doc page. I can only assume you're using a version pre-5.3, therefore:

```
echo time(); //output: 1358796864
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running PHP 5.3 or newer. It doesn't work in PHP 5.2 or older

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be helpful: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php